# What does からね mean here?

Tags: meaning, particles

> あの子 父親がいないし
> 私はこんな体でしょ？
> ずいぶん苦労させた**からね**

Can someone explain me why からね is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is から(because) + ね(ending particle). The sentence means *Because the child has had lots of hardships, ...*. The omitted '...' should be understood from context.